# Casting element to user defined type in SQL functions in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, function, types, casting

Say, I have composite type `id_and_name`.

```
CREATE TYPE id_and_name AS (id integer, name text);
```

I want to use this `(id, name)` structure as parameter in function, but I want that function user wouldn't need to cast manually: `SELECT fun((1, 'name')::id_and_name)`; user should be good with `SELECT fun((1, 'name'))`. That means that my function parameter will be `anyelement` or similar and I should cast it to `id_and_name` in function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fun(anyelement)
RETURNS id_and_name AS $$
    SELECT $1::id_and_name;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

For some reason `SELECT fun((1, 'name'))` gives me error:

```
ERROR:  cannot cast type record to id_and_name
LINE 2:     SELECT $1::id_and_name;
                     ^
```

While the same query from function with substituted parameter works fine:

```
SELECT (1, 'name')::id_and_name;
```

How should I do such casting in functions?

I'm on PostgreSQL 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it is preferable to specify argument. Otherwise you may use `row_to_json` to extract individual record elements and cast them

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fun(anyelement)
RETURNS id_and_name AS $$
   SELECT (j->>'f1',j->>'f2')::id_and_name from row_to_json($1) as j;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=804e0dc22f18e7356195c446cb282dd6)